# pig script error 1200 null

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I run the pig script but it returns error 1200. It seems to be something like a **NullPointerException** error. Here are the script and errors. How to fix it?

Script:

```
A = load 'hdfs://url/input' using PigStorage(':') AS (id: chararray, name:chararray); 

B = foreach A generate $0 as id;

store B into 'hdfs://tmp/output';
```

Errors:

```
Pig logfile dump:

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: null

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. null
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1689)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1409)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:342)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:367)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:353)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:478)
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:283)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:223)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: Failed to parse: null
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1676)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient$AuthenticationPost.extractResult(SwiftRestClient.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient$AuthenticationPost.extractResult(SwiftRestClient.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient.perform(SwiftRestClient.java:1407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient.authenticate(SwiftRestClient.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient.authIfNeeded(SwiftRestClient.java:1299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient.preRemoteCommand(SwiftRestClient.java:1315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.http.SwiftRestClient.headRequest(SwiftRestClient.java:1015)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.snative.SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.stat(SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.snative.SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.getObjectMetadata(SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.snative.SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.getObjectMetadata(SwiftNativeFileSystemStore.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.swift.snative.SwiftNativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(SwiftNativeFileSystem.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:200)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata.findMetaFile(JsonMetadata.java:113)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonMetadata.getSchema(JsonMetadata.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage.getSchema(PigStorage.java:517)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:853)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3479)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1536)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1013)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:553)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I have reproduced at my end and it seems to work fine. Can you share some sample data. It should not give you any such error. Also, let us know what version of PIG are you using I tested on 0.12 Also, how you are running your pig script is it in local mode or Mapreduce mode.

Comment: hi, Rajnish, I run it on oozie, the PIG version is 0.12. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer. Because the password in datasource is the wrong one in my situation. So it give such error.

Comment: Great its common for all of us to commit such mistakes. Happy hadooping.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the same from my side with the below query and worked fine:

```
A = load 'hdfs://url/input' using PigStorage(':') AS (id: chararray, name:chararray);

B = foreach A generate $0 as id;

store B into 'hdfs://tmp/output' using PigStorage(':');
```

Even on storing into a HDFS path, we need to mention the storage type(`TextStorage`/ `PigStorage`)